# Design rdlc with multiple grouping

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I want to design a rdlc as shown in the image
**Report screen [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW359.png)**

I am unable to add multiple groups on the report. How can I split the rdlc to have the structure as displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a Tablix Control.
Tablix control can have multiple groups to achieve your needs.

http://gotreportviewer.com/tablix/index.html

A Video tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFCUwVwrxbU

A image Example

[http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC31097.gif](https://web.archive.org/web/20150715065251/http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC31097.gif)